# WinRT: blocking Task

Tags: asynchronous, windows-runtime, task, block, async-await

I'm implementing network layer of my application, that is using an asynchronous JSON-RPC protocol.

In order to communicate with the server, i'd like to make a method that will send a proper request, wait until the server sends response, and return it. Everything with use of async/await keywords.

Here's simplified sample code:

string response;

```
Task<string> SendRequest(string methodName, string methodParams)
{
    string request = generateRequest(methodName, methodParams);

    await Send(request); // this will send using DataWriter, and StreamSocket

    // block Task until response arrives

    return response;
}


async void ReceiveLoop()
{
    while (true)
    {
            uint numStrBytes = await _reader.LoadAsync(BufferSize);

            string msg = _reader.ReadString(numStrBytes);

            response = msg;

            // unblock previously blocked SendRequest
        }        
    }
}

async void main()
{
    RecieveLoop();  
}

async void SendButtonPressed()
{
    string response = await SendRequest("Test method", "Test params");

    Debug.WriteLine("Response = " + response);
}
```

The main problem with this pattern it this blocking action. This action should block current Task, and allow to handle timeout.
I've tried to use ManualResetEvent, and WaitOne(int) to handle this, but it freezes whole Thread, and because I'm using async/await only, it freezes whole application (UI Thread to me more precise).

The solution, that looks quite hacky for me is that I can use Task.Delay with CancellationTokens.

It looks like this:

```
...
CancellationTokenSource cts;
int timeout = 10000;

Task<string> SendRequest(string methodName, string methodParams)
{
    ... (prepare request, and send)

    cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

    try
    {
        await Task.Delay(timeout, cts.Token);
    } catch(TaskCanceledException)
    {

    }

    // do rest
}

async void ReceiveLoop()
{
    // init recieve loop, and recieve message

    cts.Cancel();      
}
```

The problem with that solution (besides it looks like a hack) is performance - every request there is an excetion thrown, that needs to be handled (skipped in that case). This one is slow, and it hurts :)

How can I do it in more elegant way? Is there any other option to block a Task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the receive and send loops into one loop that is trigged by the send button:

```
while(!cancel) {
    await sendRequest();
    await receiveResponse();
}
```

Not sure if you even need the loop then because I don't know your exact requirements. It could look like this:

```
await sendRequest();
await receiveResponse();
```

That would execute a single request-response-cycle.

---

Reading your comment below I want to add the following: You're right, now you need both loops.  I'd tackle this by first creating a class to represent a request that is in flight:

```
class Request { int ID; object Response; TaskCompletionCource CompletedTask; }
```

When sending something, you create an instance of this class and add it to a `Dictionary<int, Request>`. The `ID` is a shared identifier that the server can use to respond to your request (I understand multiple requests can be outstanding).

When receiving a response you save the result and mark the `CompletedTask` as completed. Sour send method should look like:

```
var request = CreateRequest();
await sendRequest(request);
await request.CompletedTask.Task;
return request.Response;
```

The `TaskCompletionSource` will act as an event. The `Request` class encapsulates all related data.

Comment: The problem is that I need recieve loop, because this app will use bi-directional JSON-RPC, so server will can execute remote method on the app at any time.

App should look for incoming messages all the time.

Comment: I have added my thoughts on this.

Comment: Ok, thanks for this one, but as I've mentioned before, I need to handle timeout.

Is there any way to handle it more elegant than checking in the separate thread, which TaskCompletionSource-s are too old, and Complete them manually?

Comment: You can timeout your operation like this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/11/10/10235834.aspx That does the TCS completion under the covers.

Comment: In my post below (with full solution) i've aksed a question, but it can be overlooked, so I'll ask it again here:

"really, aren't there any other ways to block Tasks? What about critical sections, aren't there any Mutexes for Tasks?"

Comment: There are. In .NET 4.5 there is SemaphoreSlim.WaitAsync. Or Google for AsyncLock. Under the hood they are doing the same thing: Create a TCS and complete it at the right moment. You can use the technique that is most convenient to you.

Comment: You can write yourself an AsyncEvent if you want. It would be simple wrapper around a TCS.

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

With help of usr, I've managed to write this code, that blocks current task, with timeout:

TaskTimeout extension:

```
internal struct VoidTypeStruct{}

 public static class TaskTimeoutExtension
    {
        public static async Task TimeoutAfter(this Task task, int millisecondsTimeout)
        {
            if (task == await Task.WhenAny(task, Task.Delay(millisecondsTimeout)))
                await task;
            else
                throw new TimeoutException();
        }
    }
```

Blocking a Task:

```
var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<VoidTypeStruct>();

try
{
    await Task.Run(async () => { await tcs.Task; }).TimeoutAfter(RequestTimeout);
}
catch (TimeoutException)
{                           
}

// store tcs variable somewhere
```

Unblocking a task:

```
tcs.SetResult(new VoidTypeStruct());
```

This works quite fast (at least much better than previous solution).

At the end question: really, aren't there any other ways to block Tasks? What about critical sections, aren't there any Mutexes for Tasks?